# How to I replace text with an image in a nav_link Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my nav link

```
 <%= nav_link 'Loved', loved_properties_path %>
```

This is how i would usually insert an image

```
<%= image_tag 'desc.svg', class: "imgstar" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define as below,

```
<%= nav_link loved_properties_path do %>
  <%= image_tag 'desc.svg', class: "imgstar" %>
<% end %>
```

Similar like `link_to` with blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the argument:

```
<%= nav_link image_tag("desc.svg", class: "imgstar"), loved_properties_path %>
```

I encourage you to read some basic book about Ruby before proceeding.